# github actions - issue in checkout action

Tags: jenkins, github, terraform, aws-cloud9, github-actions-runners

I am new to github action runners. I have created a test-master branch from the master and another feature branch also taken out of master test-feature. My test-master branch has a workflow related to terraform. However, I am getting error in the git checkout action PFB the code and error.

```
name: 'Terraform'
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@test-master

    # Install the latest version of Terraform CLI and configure the Terraform CLI configuration file with a Terraform Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

    # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    # Checks that all Terraform configuration files adhere to a canonical format
    - name: Terraform Format
      id: fmt
      run: terraform fmt --recursive
```

Whenever I am trying to raise a pull request from the test-feature to test-master It runs the workflow and generates the error.
Error: Unable to resolve action `actions/checkout@test-master`, unable to find version `test-master`

Kindly guide me why is it not recognizing the test-maser branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to *use* an action, you specify the action name and the *version of the action* to run.  This line:

```
    - uses: actions/checkout@test-master
```

indicates that you want to use the `actions/checkout` action at version `test-master`.  There is no such version of the action.

You want [`actions/checkout@v2`](https://github.com/actions/checkout).  If you want to check out *your* branch called `test-master`, specify it as an option to the action.  For example:

```
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: 'test-master'
```

Comment: do u have any idea what is difference between actions/checkout@v2 and actions/checkout@master

Comment: `actions/checkout@master` will run the code in the master branch _instead_ of the code in the `v2` branch.  The `v2` branch tracks the latest release - you should use that.

Comment: v2 branch tracks the latest release for which branch master or the test-master i.e. the branch present in ref tag

Comment: `v2` is the latest release of the `actions/checkout` action.  It was explicitly created by the GitHub Actions team.  It has nothing to do with the branch present in the `ref` tag.

Comment: so the actions/checkout@master has nothing to do with the master branch of github repo. It is also created by Github Actions team

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the master branch of _your_ GitHub repo, that's correct.  It refers to the master branch of https://github.com/actions/checkout

Comment: Hi Edward Thomson, each time my master workflow is getting executed even after giving the above code in workflow in the test-master branch. I want the workflow present in my test-master branch gets executed instead of master

Comment: You can't arbitrarily run a workflow out of a different branch.  Actions will run the workflow in a branch, according to the configuration.  See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#configuring-workflow-events